# How to have long running threads in heroku to listen to multiple aws sqs queues inside rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have two tasks named `task "sqs:listen_converted"` and `task "sqs:listen_failed"`.

The first one listens to converted files and create a record for it in postgres.

The second set a flag in file record saying that the conversion failed.

These tasks have to listen forever a SQS Queue and read messages published to it.
Their code in a simple way is:

```
  task "sqs:listen_converted" => :environment do
      queue = AWS::SQS::Queue.new(SQSADDR['converted'])

      queue.poll do |msg|
      begin
         ...
      end
  end

  task "sqs:listen_failed" => :environment do
      queue = AWS::SQS::Queue.new(SQSADDR['failed'])

      queue.poll do |msg|
      begin
         ...
      end
  end
```

Well, in heroku I could have these two process running executing the command:

```
ps:scale sqs_converted=1 sqs_failed=1
```

Unfortunately doing this way I will have to pay $36 for each one.

How can I have it running on a single dyno on heroku in background?

Maybe running detached rakes process via heroku-api gem?

```
heroku = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => 'api_key')
heroku.post_ps('myapp', "rake sqs:listen_converted", { :attach => false })
heroku.post_ps('myapp', "rake sqs:listen_failed", { :attach => false })
```

Thanks!